# Can I get Nautilus to show me folder details on mouse hover?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

In Windows Explorer, one can view folder contents' details such as size and number of files on mouse hover. Is that also possible in Nautilus? In other words, how can I trigger Nautilus, if possible, to display a tool tip or notification box of some sort on mouse over a folder or directory?

Comment: Not exactly, but you can adjust the icon captions in Edit/Preferences/Display (tab) and then adjust the three values to suit you. I have mine set to Size, None, and None. Individual files list their size, and folders list an item count.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Yes I did that already. I set mine to Size, Type and Date Modified. What I want to happen, if possible, is to make Nautilus display a notification box when I point or hover my mouse on a folder.

Comment: I don't think this can be done. The simplest workaround is probably gnome-sushi (in the software center) which will give you the data you want, but you would need to tap the space bar instead of the mouseover event triggering it.

Comment: The only problem with sushi is ,it works for Folders and directories in matters of displaying size and modification date , but on multimedia files , it plays them ( IMO it was meant for previewing them)

Comment: @TomBrossman I would like to accept your comment as an answer. Can you move it as answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks, but just accept Uri's answer. It mentions my comment and I already upvoted it, which marks it as 'answered' in the system here.

Comment: You can vote for this feature here: http://community.linuxmint.com/idea/view/4354 Personally, I continue to be amazed that this isn't already supported. I haven't used Windows for years, but hovering for more information is such a common UX paradigm, that it's stunning that open source devs haven't thrown this in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither Thunar, PCManFM, nor Nautilus have this feature, I don't know about Dolphin as I don't have it Installed, while I think is possible they could have it they don't currently use it.

As @Tom mentioned in the comments, Gnome Sushi is the closest to have that but you need to press the Space bar  for the window to show and I don't know if if it's a bug only affecting me but the Sushi window uses a Black background with black text making it useless but you can still try it.

Comment: Black text sounds like a bug. I'm using the default Ambiance theme in Unity and I see white text.

Comment: Yeah just switched various themes and Indeed some use black and some use white text.

Answer (score 0):

No, as I know, there is no such a method. But you can right click -> go to Preferences.

There you can look how many files are in the folder, how big they are etc.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It is actually Properties not Preferences and I do that too but looking at the status bar is actually much quicker than right-clicking. I was just wondering if it is possible to have Nautilus display a tool tip or notification box of some sort on mouse over a folder or directory.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is because I am using the German version of Ubuntu.
Is this question closed or are you looking for another solution? I think there was a function in nautilus-elementary, but I don't know anymore.

Could you also mark the question as completed when it is?

Comment: I am still waiting for answers, hope this will not be closed down. Haven't tried nautilus-elementary, but I will check if it does have that feature.

Comment: Nautilus-elementary is dead by the way it was a mod for Nautilus 2